# Do i need to call garbage collector inside my Dispose() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dispose

I have a question on the write syntx to implement the Dispose inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application.

now i created a new asp.net mvc-5 web application using Visual Studio 2013 , and i mapped my database tables inside an edmx file. then i created a new Controller class. now the default code for `Dispose()` is as follow at the end of the controller class:-

```
public class DeptsController : Controller
    {
  private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

  //code goes here..

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

but at the same time i find many online articles and books which use the following syntax to Dispose the current request as in this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application):-

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
```

so i have this question :- which syntax for dispose i should/prefer to use ? and do these 2 approaches generate the same result ?

Comment: I code looks nearly identical between 2 examples you claim to be significantly different... Please clarify what part you believe is different (assuming you understand what `override` means)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov on the code generated by visual studio there is no call to :- "GC.SuppressFinalize(this);" Also there is not any statement to do :-  "this.disposed = true;"

Comment: Fair point `Controller` does not have `this.disposed = true;` (only `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`)... Also still not sure how you expect your derived class implementation to look like.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i expect them to be similar to the code that was generated by VS 2013 using EF Controller templete.. where it does not call GC.SuppressFinalize.. so not sure why on the example they use it ? and is it necessary to call GC inside my Dispose method?

Comment: What the point of calling `GC.SuppressFinalize` twice (as base class already does it)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov now as i mentioned my question is why the link which i provide explicitly calls  the GC inside ? so which code is preferred to use in this case ?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you understand that you are talking about 2 different cases - derived class overriding parent's `Dispose(bool)` (in case of `DeptsController`) vs. base class providing virtual method for derived classes to override (in case of `StudentRepository`) ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes sure i know the differences,, so you mean currently the "protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)" inside the StudentRepository is not being called by the controller ? and is not being called in the whole tutorial link ? and it is there just in-case i want to create a new repository which have the StudentRepository as its base class ???

Comment: No - `studentRepository.Dispose();` is clearly inside Controller's Dispose. Just take a look at `Controller.Dispose` (any decompiler would do, or get sources http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/). I hope that would clarify what I'm trying to say (and re-read your sample in the post - you may be talking about different pieces of code compare to what actually in the post)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok so you mean at the end calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this); is redundant since the base class Controller already calls it , and when i call this  base.Dispose(disposing); inside my Controller the GC will be called ..

Answer (score 1):

If your class has a `~DeptsController` method (a.k.a a finalize method or "destructor"), and all it does is call `Dispose()`, you need to call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` to prevent `Dispose` from being called twice.

If your class does not have a destructor then there is no need.

Comment: While reasonable suggestion, you probably wanted to say something about "If base class ..." instead of your current answer as OP shows `override` in the sample.

Comment: @John thanks for the repl.. now my Controller class does not have any destructor

Comment: @johnG whatever John Wu said only true for direct implementation of `Dispose` on sealed class, if class is not sealed you can't prevent derived classes to have destructor and hence pattern shown in your post where base suppresses finalization always is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement IDisposble, just use the implementation that visual studio will build. The comments in the generated code tell you exactly when you do and do not need to call the GC. Example of the generated code:

```
        private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~ChampionGgCallerHttpClient() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```